# Is it possible to import a (gnome) keyring to another from its binary files

Tags: password-recovery, gnome-keyring

(This question was originally posted on AskUbuntu, but got no good answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217709 )

I have recently set up an Ubuntu box using Gnome desktop, and want to import data I have saved from an older Ubuntu computer. These data include a gnome keyring, which I (rather stupidly) copied the encrypted files instead of exporting.

What I did

> cp -R ~/.gnome2/keyring /backup/gnome2_keyring

Given that I still know the session passwords I used for the corresponding user account on the old computer, what can I do to recover/import passwords/data from the keyring?

This is a home user question, and has to be done only once: I am not concerned with security problems: I'll wipe my free space afterwards and that will be enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how recent seahorse is.  For a sufficiently old seahorse you could just copy the given keyring files into the new ~/.gnome2/keyring directory.  For a more recent seahorse you would copy the keyring files into ~/.local/share/keyrings.

Recent versions of seahorse are annoying in that you have to explicitly go to the view menu and state that you want to view by keyring or it will only show passwords for keyrings that are already open, but once you do that change it should work.  Before I figured this out, it looked as if seahorse wasn't seeing the key rings.